# The Most efficient algorithm for a program that returns true if the two strings only differ by one character

Tags: hash-tables, dictionaries

We have a list of strings with the same length. Each string only contains a, b and c.(For instance : aabcc)
The program gets a string and returns true if the two strings(input and the list of strings) only differ by one character.

```
A = {cacab cbabc}
cbbaa : False
cbaac : True
```

My first thought was to solve it with brute force which the worst-case time complexity is `O(n^2)`. Is there any way to solve it with hash table or any other data structure?

Comment: "Approximate pattern matching"

Comment: Using a hashtable to count occurrences of each letter appearing in each word is a good idea. This could solve the problem in expected $O(n)$ time.

Comment: I think you mean brute force is $O(\ell n)$ where the list is of length $\ell$

Comment: Nathaniel , could you explain more?